# web2py login to site script/function

Tags: python, web2py

i would create a script that login to a website using username and password stored in my table.

I've got a table

```
db.define_table('clients',
    Field('client'),
    Field('username'),
    Field('password')
        )
```

I would configure in my controller a function that use the username and the password from my record to login in a website

in the login form of the website the id and psw are called

```
'idutente' and 'idutepasswd'
```

i hope i gave you enought information to help me, tel me if you need more.
(sorry for my english)

Comment: Is there some reason you cannot use web2py's built-in Auth system, which includes this functionality?

Comment: Yes, i don't have to login in web2py, but in another website, so the function must open a new site use the "username" and "password" stored in my table and login the site.

Comment: Maybe it isn't clear, the funcion must autologin the site without all the people know the password.

Comment: If you want your users to be logged into this other site from their own browsers, the login submission must come from the browser, which means you will have to send the user id and password to the browser in clear text (you could hide these items from view, but a knowledgeable user will be able to inspect the values). Do you need to keep the id and password secret? Do you have control over the other website (if so, you should instead implement a proper single sign-on solution)?

Comment: I have no control of the other website, and i only need to hide these from view, don't need to keep them secret, in the table these will be write in clear.

Comment: In that case, you probably need to create a web page that includes a form that gets submitted directly to the website's login URL, with the form submission triggered automatically via Javascript. However, this will not work if the website requires other special data to be submitted with the login, such as a CSRF token (for example, you could not do this with another web2py site, as its login form is protected with a CSRF token).

Comment: Also, what you are doing sounds potentially dangerous. It appears you are somehow getting logins to another website (that you don't control) and (a) storing the passwords in clear text in your own database, and (b) sending those passwords to user's browsers. What exactly is the purpose of this system?

Comment: That the users that login in the other site don't know the password, so if a user don't work for me anymore i don't have to change all the passwords.

Comment: But as noted above, users will be able to discover the passwords, so to be safe, you would have to change them anyway. And it is definitely a bad idea to store passwords for other accounts in clear text in your database.

Comment: Mate, im happy that you are worring about the secury of my request, but i don't care about that, i only would know if you are able to do that and can tell me the code to do that, i would use the same method to store the acces of my accounts in the various website, if you don't know how to do that thank you anyway.

Comment: As already noted, what you are trying to do may not be *possible*, depending on how the site in question handles logins. And although *you* may not care about the security issues, it is possible you could be putting *other people* at risk.